# MVC AJAX JQuery - Trapping the ID of the control that called the Javascript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm playing and trying to learn a little more about AJAX in MVC.

Currently, I have the following block of code in an MVC view.  The idea is that when the link is clicked, the app will fire the FlagInappropriate() method in the controller and display a message in the link that was clicked and disable the link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function flagInappropriate(postId) {
        var url = "Home/FlagAsInappropriate/" + postId;
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $('#LinkAppropriate').text('Post has been flagged');
                $('#LinkAppropriate').attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
            } else {
                alert('Post cannot be flagged');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<h1>Index</h1>
<a href="javascript:flagInappropriate(1)" id="LinkAppropriate">Flag as inappropriate</a>
```

Currently this is working and have no complaints with it.  My next step is to be able to have any number of links call this javascript method.  See the example below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function flagInappropriate(postId) {
        var url = "Home/FlagAsInappropriate/" + postId;
        var callingObject = CallingObjectIDGetter();
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $('#' + callingObject).text('Post has been flagged');
                $('#' + callingObject).attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
            } else {
                alert('Post cannot be flagged');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<h1>Index</h1>
<a href="javascript:flagInappropriate(1)" id="Link1">Flag as inappropriate</a>
<a href="javascript:flagInappropriate(1)" id="Link2">Flag as inappropriate</a>
<a href="javascript:flagInappropriate(1)" id="Link3">Flag as inappropriate</a>
<a href="javascript:flagInappropriate(1)" id="Link4">Flag as inappropriate</a>
<a href="javascript:flagInappropriate(1)" id="Link5">Flag as inappropriate</a>
```

Given this scenario, how do I derive and manipulate the object that called the Javascript method? In short, what would I use in place of the line **var callingObject = CallingObjectIDGetter();**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding the events in your markup, why don't you leverage jQuery and do this:

markup:

```
<a href="Home/FlagAsInappropriate/1" id="Link1">Flag as inappropriate</a>
... more links go here...
```

javascript:

```
function flagInappropriate(callingObject, url) {
    $.post(url, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#' + callingObject).text('Post has been flagged');
            $('#' + callingObject).attr("href", "javascript:void(0);");
        } else {
            alert('Post cannot be flagged');
        }
    });
}

$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    flagInappropriate($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('href'));
});
```